# SQL: how to combine multiple views into one view?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following view, that groups requests by minute for last 30 minutes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "public"."last_thirty_minutes_stats" AS 
 SELECT requests.endpoint_id,
    date_trunc('minute'::text, requests.created_at) AS "time",
    avg(requests.response_time) AS avg
   FROM requests
  WHERE (age(now(), (requests.created_at)::timestamp with time zone) < '00:30:00'::interval)
  GROUP BY requests.endpoint_id, (date_trunc('minute'::text, requests.created_at));
```

Now I need to group also by hour for the last 24 hours. Am I required to write a second view or can I customize the existant one with params? thank you.

Comment: Views do not take parameters.  You could define a table function, though.

Answer (score 1):

SQL functions could be used as "parameterized vies". For example:

```
create view databases as
  select * from pg_database
  where not datistemplate;

select * from databases where datname ilike '%post%';
```

or

```
create function databases(text default null) returns setof pg_database language sql as $$
  select * from pg_database
  where not datistemplate and ($1 is null or datname ilike '%'||$1||'%') $$;

select * from databases('post');
```